How to fetch the amount of tokens pooled into Uniswap V3 pool
I would like to fetch the amount of USDC.e (or any other token) pooled into the Uniswap v3 pool on Arbitrum using Node.js.
I figured out how to fetch the current split when the price is in the range, however, I also need to know the original investments in the pool.
Wallet:0x4a84c73d6bbf00476bc4691c699cc8e875709aeb
Position id:2773390
Arbiscan: https://arbiscan.io/tx/0x593ea01259c90b998c0ef54822df3c39c3cbb609d7b767e8f927414a6af0f99f
Please help me with the Javascript code to fetch the original invested amount.
Thank you in advance!
